# Showing wrong count of questions and answers in Network Profile accounts section specifically Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts

Currently it's showing as 20 and 19 for questions and answers but actual count is 57 & 119.

Here are profile links:

https://stackexchange.com/users/4152649/ali786?tab=accounts
https://stackoverflow.com/users/3404637/ali786

I think it's because of this issue:
[Accounts got merged accidentally or automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322755/accounts-got-merged-accidentally-or-automatically)